# SQL Agent Logon - What is going on?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-agent

I have a DTSX package that is called from a SQL Agent Job.

The DTSX package references a file at a fixed location (e.g. e:\mssql\myfile.txt).

On most machines, this location exists, but on some I have to manually map this (which is not a problem - I know a better solution would be to use package conifgurations to dynamically pull the file location, but this is not an option here - and anyway I'd like to understand what is going on)

I have set up the agent service to run as a specific user (e.g. **myuser**)

When I log on as this user and map the directory, then run the dtsx package directly, then all goes well.

When I run the package through a SQL Agent Job, the file cannot be found. If I add a command line job step to the agent job to map the drive:

```
net use e: \\svr\location
```

Then all works file also.

So what is going on in the backgound? How come the SQL Agent user requries the drive mapping even when I am logged in as this user.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you SQL Agent is not running under the myuser that you have logged under. You can verify that in your sql job history error message.

Go to services and change to sql agent service to run under the service account myuser.

Also another suggestion would be to share the svr folder to have permission for myuser. This way you have to worry about the folder path.